# Add new document templates to a library

Tags: list, document-template

I have created a document workspace library, but now users can only select one document template when clicking "New Document".

[image]

I have found this screenshot above, but could anyone explain me where I can add such additional templates as seen in the screenshot?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to Library Settings -> Advanced settings -> Set **Allow management of content types?** to **Yes** -> click **OK** button
2. Site settings -> Site content types -> Create -> Enter Name (f.e. PowerPoint), add description -> Select parent content type from: Document content types -> Parent Content Type: Document -> click **OK**  button -> click on **Advanced settings** link -> Upload a new document template (f.e. powerpoint.pptx) -> click **OK**
3. Go to Library Settings -> In content types area click **Add from existing site content types** -> select type, that you created -> click **OK**

Comment: In addition, you may need to create new Document Content Types for your additional templates. A Document content type can only have 1 template.

Comment: ok, I will try this out :) (About the my post on serverfault: didn't know there was this sharepoint stackexchange site)